# Как использовать Go в С#/С++

Tags: c#, golang, c++

Есть проект на С#/С++ на винде. Вопрос в том, как подключить и использовать в проекте язык Go? Слышал, что DLL на Go ещё не придумали, но как же тогда быть?

Comment: напишите на go сервис, который будет доступен по http как rest сервис.

Comment: http://dennisforbes.ca/index.php/2013/07/31/demonstrating-gos-easy-c-interop/

Answer (score 3):

Вариант 1:
Из программы на C#/C++ запускаешь программу на go
Программа на go открывает порт/pite/file как удобнее, наверно лучше port
Запустившая программа на C#/C++ подключается к этому порту и выполняет необходимые запросы

Порт открывать может C#/C++ программа а к ней подключаться запускаемая go программа

Язык на котором может общаться программа можешь придумать сам, начиная от банального json заканчивая бинарным...

Вариант 2:
на go ты можешь в код программы вставлять код написанный на Си, думаю дальше фантазия подскажет что при таком подходе ты можешь сделать некий "коннектор" который позволит программе на go общаться с сторонними процессами операционки...

У кого есть еще варианты пишите. Я сам использую пока что только вот эти два способа, вариант 2 более старый, вариант 1 более новый, более удобный.

Comment: Собственно, способ №1 практически не зависит от языков.